# Focus on next item in container

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way to programmatically focus on the next focusable node in a container without directly calling on a specific component's [`requestFocus()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#requestFocus--) method? This functionality would be similar to pressing the tab button to traverse focus between components where [`disabled`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setDisable-boolean-) nodes are skipped.

Comment: Why the normal TAB behavior is not working for you?

Comment: The user expects to be able to use the ENTER key like the TAB key to traverse fields. In addition, they would like the ENTER key to do some error checking and the TAB key to skip error checking.

Comment: I personally for my forms use `setOnAction()` on input and call next input `requestFocus()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no public method for this. *Only hacks and workarounds.*

You could use the node's

```
impl_traverse(Direction.NEXT);
```

method. But this one is deprecated and **could be removed** at any time and your code breaks with a new java version.

Alternatively you could catch the enter key and fire a tab key event. But that's equally ugly.

Or if you are in a textfield you could do it like this:

```
if( textfield.getSkin() instanceof BehaviorSkinBase) {
    ((BehaviorSkinBase) textfield.getSkin()).getBehavior().traverseNext();  
}
```

But that's also discouraged since it isn't api.

And even if you'd use reflection to access the scene's traverse method like this:

```
Method[] allMethods = scene.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m : allMethods) {
    String mname = m.getName();
    if (mname.startsWith("traverse")) {
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(scene, new Object[] { textfield, Direction.NEXT });
    }
}
```

you'd end up with having to provide a Direction parameter which is also discouraged.

The best thing you can do is to [comment and vote on this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090456).

Comment: There's already an [issue filed for this](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31301), you might want just to vote for it (and perhaps comment with some details as to how you would like the API to look).

Answer (score 4):

According to your use case, you may also filter and convert <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys to <kbd>Tab</kbd> on parent pane:

```
@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{
    TextField field1 = new TextField();
    TextField field2 = new TextField();
    TextField field3 = new TextField();
    VBox vbox = new VBox( field1, field2, field3 );

    vbox.addEventFilter( KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, ( KeyEvent event ) ->
    {
        if ( event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER )
        {
            KeyEvent newEvent
                    = new KeyEvent(
                            null,
                            null,
                            KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,
                            "",
                            "\t",
                            KeyCode.TAB,
                            event.isShiftDown(),
                            event.isControlDown(),
                            event.isAltDown(),
                            event.isMetaDown()
                    );

            Event.fireEvent( event.getTarget(), newEvent );
            event.consume();
        }
    } );
    final Scene scene = new Scene( vbox, 800, 600 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching and searching for a decent answer to this question, I finally wrote my own, because no answer really met my needs.

Here is my solution (Note: I am using only TextFields, so setOnAction, by default, executes when ENTER is pressed):

```
textField.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
    boolean isThisField = false;
    for (Node child : textField.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
        if (isThisField) {

            //This code will only execute after the current Node
            if (child.isFocusTraversable() && !child.isDisabled()) {
                child.requestFocus();

                //Reset check to prevent later Node from pulling focus
                isThisField = false;
            }
        } else {

            //Check if this is the current Node
            isThisField = child.equals(textField);
        }
    }

    //Check if current Node still has focus
    boolean focusChanged = !textField.isFocused();
    if (!focusChanged) {
        for (Node child : textField.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            if (!focusChanged && child.isFocusTraversable() && !child.isDisabled()) {
                child.requestFocus();

                //Update to prevent later Node from pulling focus
                focusChanged = true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For my application, I wrote a class, DoubleField, that extends TextField, and added this code to the constructor method.  That way I only had to type it once.  It works like a charm for all of my fields.